In WSO2 API Manager, user roles are being removed each time a user login through an external IdP
We want to provision a user who login from an external IdP to APIM, assign the role “test-role”, and obtain an access token that includes the scope “test-scope” associated with the test-role.
However, each time I login, the role disappears, which defeats the purpose.
Prerequisite
WSO2 APIM Version 4.3.0
OIDC Authorization Code Flow
JIT is enabled.
DB:H2
Steps

User login from an external IdP.
User is provisioned to APIM.
Grant the role “test-role” to the user.
Next time the user login from an external IdP, the role disappears.

Tried
added the following to deployment.toml
[authentication.framework.extensions]
provisioning_handler = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.provisioning.impl.SystemRolesRetainedProvisionHandler"

This did not improve anything.
[idp_role_management]
return_only_mapped_local_roles = true
return_only_mapped_local_roles_unmapped_exclusive = true

In this way, the user's role was preserved only in appearance, but the obtained access token did not include the scope “test-scope”.
these changes did not resolve the issue.
Are there any solutions or workarounds for this issue?

You have to do a role mapping when you configure the external IDP. This will map a claim coming from the external IDP to a local role (say test-role). See the section 'Add the following role mapping under the Role Configuration section:' in [1]
[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/sso/configuring-identity-server-as-external-idp-using-oidc/#configure-the-api-manager
